# How to change the weblogic t3 protocol's default listening port 7001

Tags: weblogic, port, protocols, weblogic12c

Weblogic t3 protocol's default listening port is 7001.I tried to add a new network channel to listen t3 messages,but the 7001 port can still listen the t3 messages.I wish that the 7001 port can not listen t3 messages.Weblogic's version is Weblogic 12c.
How can I solve the problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default port listens to all protocols, you cannot remove a single protocol from it. Either the default port or the default ssl port has to be active.

What you could do, is block t3 protocolls with a connection filter (note: the default implementation blocks t3 access on all ports. You would have to implement your own connection filter to change to only block specific parts)

Under `domain -> security -> filter`

Add the class `weblogic.security.net.ConnectionFilterImpl` and the filter rule `0.0.0.0/0 * * deny t3`

But your best option is probably to develop your own connection filter, the following Weblogic 12c Documentation should help you with that:

Using Network Connection Filters: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24485/con_filtr.htm#SCPRG389

Configuring Security for a WebLogic Domain: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24422/domain.htm#SECMG410

Comment: Thanks a lot!  After I added the Connection Filter Rules:127.0.0.1 * * allow t3 and 0.0.0.0/0 * * deny t3 , it works.